# Position elements vertically using FxFlexModule

Tags: angular, user-interface, angular-flex-layout

I am using Angulars FxFlexModule within my app. I need to move the "test" element up closer to the search box. That entire container (the text element and the search box) are using `fxLayoutAlign="start start" fxLayoutGap="8px"`. How can I push the "test" element up closer to the search box using FxFlexModule? I do not want to use absolute or relative positioning.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming your code is laid out somewhat like this:

```
<div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="start start" fxLayoutGap="8px">
  <mat-form-field>...</mat-form-field>
  <div>test</div>
</div>
```

You can delete `fxLayoutGap="8px"`, which will move "test" up 8px.

FxLayoutGap also supports negative margins so you could try `fxLayoutGap="-8px"`. Be wary if you're using mat-hints and mat-errors, they may overlap with your "test" element in this case.